# scrollPagination 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I have the file javascript.js

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {     
        var settings = { 
            nop     : 10, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
            offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
            error   : 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                        // displayed. You can change this if you want.
            delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                           // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
            scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                           // but will still load if the user clicks.
        }       
        // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }       
        // For each so that we keep chainability.
        return this.each(function() {           
            // Some variables 
            $this = $(this);
            $settings = settings;
            var offset = $settings.offset;
            var busy = false; // Checks if the scroll action is happening 
                              // so we don't run it multiple times

            // Custom messages based on settings
            if($settings.scroll == true) $initmessage = 'Loading content .....';
            else $initmessage = 'Click for more content';

            // Append custom messages and extra UI
            $this.append('<div class="content"></div><div class="loading-bar">'+$initmessage+'</div>');

            function getData() {

                // Post data to ajax.php
                $.post('infinite.php', {

                    action        : 'scrollpagination',
                    number        : $settings.nop,
                    offset        : offset,

                }, function(data) {

                    // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html($initmessage);

                    // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
                    if(data == "") { 
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error);   
                    }
                    else {

                        // Offset increases
                        offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

                        // Append the data to the content div
                        $this.find('.content').append(data);

                        // No longer busy!  
                        busy = false;
                    }   

                });

            }   

            getData(); // Run function initially

            // If scrolling is enabled
            if($settings.scroll == true) {
                // .. and the user is scrolling
                $(window).scroll(function() {

                    // Check the user is at the bottom of the element
                    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $this.height() && !busy) {

                        // Now we are working, so busy is true
                        busy = true;

                        // Tell the user we're loading posts
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html('Loading Posts');

                        // Run the function to fetch the data inside a delay
                        // This is useful if you have content in a footer you
                        // want the user to see.
                        setTimeout(function() {

                            getData();

                        }, $settings.delay);

                    }   
                });
            }

            // Also content can be loaded by clicking the loading bar/
            $this.find('.loading-bar').click(function() {

                if(busy == false) {
                    busy = true;
                    getData();
                }

            });

        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

and on index.php I have

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#content').scrollPagination({
            nop: 10, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
            offset: 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
            error: 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
            // displayed. You can change this if you want.
            delay: 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
            // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
            scroll: true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                    // but will still load if the user clicks.

        });

    });

</script>
```

I have tested on other template and everythings works fine no erros, but where I need to work I get an error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollPagination is not a function

What can I do to solve the problem..I have no idea why here is not working and on other test template is worked.

Comment: How do you reference the upper script in your html?

Comment: See if your file javascript.js is downloaded in browser before calling the function